# Do I still write String^ const in C++/CLI

Tags: .net, visual-c++, c++-cli, const-correctness

In C++ it's recommended to have const-correctness everywhere. But since in .Net world, the string content cannot be changed, (new string will be created), do I still write String^ const?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Just pass a handle to a string directly: `method(String^ string)`

Comment: ok, what if in a method, I want to define a const string, would it be better that I put const there so anyone else would know it's a not-changed string?